# How to customize wordpress function: the tags?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, post, tags

In my wordpress post I have included tags with using wordpress function

```
<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

My actual Css :

```
.postclass{
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
  }

.posttag{
  font-size:10px;
  float:left;
  color:#212121;
  margin-right:15px;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background:black;
}
```

In my template:

```
<div class="postclass">
     <?php the_tags( '<p class="posttag">', ',', '</p>' ); ?>
</div>
```

This gives me all tags in same black background .How can I get each tag text with black background each separated by comma?

Comment: sorry, but you didn't really explain what you are trying to achieve. Maybe some screenshots can help?

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/XxN2W/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following an example from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list

```
<div class="postclass">
     <?php the_tags( '<p class="posttag">', '</p><p class="posttag">', '</p>' ); ?>
</div>
```

This will wrap all tags individually in `<p class="posttag">[link]</p>`.

### Something closer to your jsfiddle:

#### PHP

```
<?php the_tags( '<ul class="postclass"><li>', ',</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

#### CSS

```
ul.postclass li {
    float: left;
}
ul.postclass li a {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

With `the_tags()` you **cannot** customize the `<a>`-tag itself as in your jsfiddle. You can only wrap it. For achieving this you'll have to work with [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) which will return an array of tag-objects you can post-process.

Comment: It doesn't separate tags .This way all tags withing same black container.

Comment: I don't know whats going on in your code but this should work. I tried to add some explanation to my answer, maybe this will help. If not, please provide the relevant parts from your code

Comment: This Jsfiddle is not the actual code, it just to show the result that what I want to implement.

Comment: how to remove anchor tag from this. only <li>tags name <li>

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. In your WordPress post.php add a div class followed with tags function like this:

```
<div class="postclass">
<?php echo esc_html__( '', 'posttag' ); ?>
</div>
```

Add this one, if you need the "#" before each tag.

```
<div class="postclass">
<?php echo esc_html__( '', 'posttag' ); ?><?php the_tags( "#", "#" ); ?>
</div>
```

2. On your CSS:

```
.postclass{
  font-size:10px;
}
.postclass a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:5px 10px;
  font-size:10px;
  color:white;
  border-radius:3px;
  background:black;
}
```

Working sample: https://koreanwave.org 
(On Desktop: hover at the bottom of image) 
(On Mobile: hover @USER-NAME)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.